# Using other than skak chess fonts

Tags: fonts, unicode, chess

I want to use other fonts than skak (merida, cases etc.). I've downloaded enpassant fonts, and even copied them to skaknew folder. However, I cannot use fonts, which do not have .pfb files, describing something like:

**error: (type 1): cannot open file for reading 'chess-merida-board-fig-raw.pfb**

My code:

```
\documentclass[paper=6in:9in,DIV=calc,12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{texmate}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\newcounter{diagrams}
\newcommand\printdiagrams{\refstepcounter{diagrams}\thediagrams}
\setboardfontfamily{chess-merida}
\setchessboard{smallboard, showmover=true, moverstyle=triangle, movershift=-1.3ex, moverlift=-1.5ex}
\newcommand\tacticboard[2][]{%
 \noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
  \centering\printdiagrams\chessboard[#2]\par
   \small\bfseries #1\strut
    \end{minipage}\hfill\ignorespaces }

    ....

\begin{document}

....

\tacticboard{setfen=6k1/4p3/3p2p1/4brp1/7q/1P2B2P/PP1Q2P1/5RK1 b}
\tacticboard{setfen=Bn3rk1/p4p1p/b2P2p1/2p1b1B1/3q4/8/P4RPP/2RQ2K1 b}
\tacticboard{setfen=8/1P6/2n1k3/8/3B1p1p/5P1p/8/5K2 w,moverlift=16.5ex}

....

\end{document}
```

Due to unicode files, I encode by LuaLatex. Also, I cannot combine chessfss and upper packages. How are the solution?

With regards, Ulvi Bajarani

Comment: The original font is here. http://www.enpassant.dk/chess/fonteng.htm . How to convert them is described in the chessfss documentation. As the author could not be contacted I can't upload my conversion to ctan. I have no idea what you mean by "chessfss and upper packages"

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for your answer! I meant by "chessfss and upper packages" that I cannot combine with each other chessfss, xskak, and texmate.

Comment: Sorry this is too vage.if you have a clash make a new question with a concrete, complete example that can be tested. (without dots)